# Store Byte array in SQLite using Blob

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, arrays

For my application I'm trying to store a byte array in my SQLite application, I'm filling my SQLite database this way:

```
public bool InsertMessage()
    {
        //create string SQl and fill it with the SQLite query for inserting a message.
        string SQL = "Insert into ClockMessages(InsertDateTime, SendDateTime, Data) Values('"+ insertdatetime + "', null, '" + data + "');";
        List<SQLiteParameter> pars = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
        pars.Add(new SQLiteParameter("InsertDateTime", insertdatetime));
        pars.Add(new SQLiteParameter("Data", data));
        //send the SQl query and it's parameters to the SQLiteDatabase class
        return SQLiteDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(SQL, pars);
    }
```

Where InsertDateTime is the DateTime.UtcNow and Data is a byte array. The output of this results in a field Data that contains: System.Byte[], Can't I just show the real byte array in that field, without showing a string? I'am using the Byte[] type everywhere to fill the Database, so I don't convert it to a string. I would like to see something like this in the Data field: 01, 54, 32, 23, 11, 02, 53. The DataType of the Data field in the database is: BLOB.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: You are not using the parameters correctly. Your code as written is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: That doesn't matter, this database is a local one and I know the people who are going to work with it, and they are everything except hackers/programmers etc

Comment: That attitude is the worst security vulnerability of all.

Comment: And if they should do an SQL injection in that database, there is no data that the user may not see, because it is data from himself and settings that he made himself.

Comment: I am surprised nobody noticed that he is concatanating `insertdatetime` and `data` in the string instead of providing parameters.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan They did, that's the whole point of why Joel complained about SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use parameters in the statement:

```
string SQL = "INSERT INTO ClockMessages (InsertDateTime, SendDateTime, Data) VALUES (@InsertDateTime, NULL, @Data)";
```

Everything else seems correct.

What you have now, calls the `ToString()` method on `insertdatetime` and `data` and concatenates the result to the sql statement. Actually you are not using any parameter in the statement.

Answer (score 4):

Use an overload of SQLiteParameter that takes the `DBType` parameter:

```
var dataParameter = new SQLiteParameter("Data", DbType.Binary) { Value = data };
pars.Add(dataParameter);
```

Comment: Now going to test that method EDIT: after trying this method is the problem that DbType.Binary is not an valid argument

Comment: What library are you using? What makes you think it is not a valid parameter: was there some kind of error?

Comment: It will tell me: Argument 3: cannot convert from byte[] to int

Comment: My apologies I misread the docs. Could you try the edit above?

Comment: Are you sure that the byte array itself does not contain the text 'System.Byte[]'?

Comment: No it isn't containing System.Byte[] it contains something like: 01, 20, 32, 12, 23, 53